# Is there a way to build multiple semantic-ui themes in the same project?

Tags: gulp, semantic-ui

I'm trying to create a prototype at the moment and keep running into walls.

I'm working on a project where we hope to have one code base that all of our end-users use and where the organization that user is affiliated with will determine the skin(css file) that gets applied to the site. Semantic-UI seems like a great fit for this as it has the concept of themes and a build process around it. I wanted to tap into the power of this build process without having to completely rewrite it.

**Is there a way to run a semantic ui build task and have it produce multiple css files?**

Here is what I've tried so far:

**ATTEMPT 1**
After running `npm install --save-dev semantic-ui` and choosing all of the default options on the install, I updated the `semantic/tasks/build.js` file to the following:

```
/*******************************
          Build Task
*******************************/

var
  // dependencies
  gulp         = require('gulp-help')(require('gulp')),
  runSequence  = require('run-sequence'),
  print        = require('gulp-print'),
  // config
  config       = require('./config/user'),
  install      = require('./config/project/install'),

  // task sequence
  tasks        = []
;


// sub-tasks
if(config.rtl) {
  require('./collections/rtl')(gulp);
}
require('./collections/build')(gulp);

const orgs = require('../../organizations.json').orgs;
module.exports = function(callback) {
    tasks.push('build-javascript');
    tasks.push('build-assets');
    var lastTaskName = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < orgs.length; i ++) {
    console.info('Building Semantic');
    const org = orgs[i];

    gulp.task(`copy semantic ${org}`, function() {
      console.info(`copy semantic ${org}`);
      return gulp.src(`./orgs/${org}/semantic.json`)
                 .pipe(print())
                 .pipe(gulp.dest('../'));
    });

    gulp.task(`copy theme ${org}`, function() {
      console.info(`copy theme ${org}`);
      return gulp.src(`./orgs/${org}/theme.config`)
                 .pipe(print())
                 .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/'));
    });

    gulp.task(`build css ${org}`, [`build-css`]);

    if( !install.isSetup() ) {
      console.error('Cannot find semantic.json. Run "gulp install" to set-up Semantic');
      return 1;
    }
    tasks.push(`copy semantic ${org}`);
    tasks.push(`copy theme ${org}`);
    tasks.push(`build css ${org}`);
  };

  runSequence(...tasks, callback);
};
```

The idea behind this being that for every organization it would have its own `semantic.json` and `theme.config` files. These would overwrite the default files(`/semantic.json` and `/semantic/src/theme.config` respectively) and then create a new `build-css` task for each one.

***The problem with this approach is that the build process only seems to use the original `semantic.json` file that was in place before the build started even though it is successfully getting overwritten.*** For instance, in the original `semantic.json` file, the value for `output.packaged` is 'dist/'. `semantic.json` is successfully getting overwritten and the `output.packaged` value is `dist/org1` before the `build-css` task gets executed, but all of the output files still end up in 'dist/'.

---

**ATTEMPT 2**
After running `npm install --save-dev semantic-ui` and choosing all of the default options on the install, I updated the `semantic/tasks/build/css.js` file to the following:

```
const console = require('better-console');
const extend = require('extend');
const fs = require('fs');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const chmod = require('gulp-chmod');
const minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
const clone = require('gulp-clone');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const concatCSS = require('gulp-concat-css');
const dedupe = require('gulp-dedupe');
const flatten = require('gulp-flatten');
const header = require('gulp-header');
const gulpif = require('gulp-if');
const less = require('gulp-less');
const plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
const print = require('gulp-print');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const replace = require('gulp-replace');
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
const requireDotFile = require('require-dot-file');
const runSequence = require('run-sequence');

const config = require('../config/project/config');
const defaults = require('../config/defaults');
const install = require('../config/project/install');
const tasks = require('../config/tasks');
const banner = tasks.banner;
const comments = tasks.regExp.comments;
const log = tasks.log;
const settings = tasks.settings;
const filenames = tasks.filenames;

const orgs = requireDotFile(`organizations.json`, __dirname).orgs;

module.exports = function(callback) {
    orgs.forEach(org => {
        const userConfig = requireDotFile(`semantic.${org}.json`, __dirname);
        const gulpConfig = (!userConfig) ? extend(true, {}, defaults) : extend(false, {}, defaults, userConfig);
        const compiledConfig = config.addDerivedValues(gulpConfig);
        const globs = compiledConfig.globs;
        const assets = compiledConfig.paths.assets;
        const output = compiledConfig.paths.output;
        const source = compiledConfig.paths.source;

        const cssExt = { extname: `.${org}.css` };
        const minCssExt = { extname: `.${org}.min.css` };

        let tasksCompleted = 0;
        let maybeCallback  = function() {
            tasksCompleted++;
            if(tasksCompleted === 2 * orgs.length) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        let stream;
        let compressedStream;
        let uncompressedStream;

        console.info('Building CSS');

        if( !install.isSetup() ) {
            console.error('Cannot build files. Run "gulp install" to set-up Semantic');
            return;
        }

        // unified css stream
        stream = gulp.src(source.definitions + '/**/' + globs.components + '.less')
            .pipe(plumber(settings.plumber.less))
            .pipe(less(settings.less))
            .pipe(autoprefixer(settings.prefix))
            .pipe(replace(comments.variables.in, comments.variables.out))
            .pipe(replace(comments.license.in, comments.license.out))
            .pipe(replace(comments.large.in, comments.large.out))
            .pipe(replace(comments.small.in, comments.small.out))
            .pipe(replace(comments.tiny.in, comments.tiny.out))
            .pipe(flatten())
        ;

        // two concurrent streams from same source to concat release
        uncompressedStream = stream.pipe(clone());
        compressedStream   = stream.pipe(clone());

        // uncompressed component css
        uncompressedStream
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(replace(assets.source, assets.uncompressed))
            .pipe(rename(cssExt))
            .pipe(gulpif(compiledConfig.hasPermission, chmod(compiledConfig.permission)))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(output.uncompressed))
            .pipe(print(log.created))
            .on('end', function() {
            runSequence(`package uncompressed css ${org}`, maybeCallback);
            })
        ;

        // compressed component css
        compressedStream
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(clone())
            .pipe(replace(assets.source, assets.compressed))
            .pipe(minifyCSS(settings.minify))
            .pipe(rename(minCssExt))
            .pipe(gulpif(compiledConfig.hasPermission, chmod(compiledConfig.permission)))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(output.compressed))
            .pipe(print(log.created))
            .on('end', function() {
            runSequence(`package compressed css ${org}`, maybeCallback);
            })
        ;
        });

        gulp.task(`package uncompressed css ${org}`, function() {
            return gulp.src(`${output.uncompressed}/**/${globs.components}.${org}${globs.ignored}.css`)
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(dedupe())
            .pipe(replace(assets.uncompressed, assets.packaged))
            .pipe(concatCSS(`semantic.${org}.css`, settings.concatCSS))
                .pipe(gulpif(compiledConfig.hasPermission, chmod(compiledConfig.permission)))
                .pipe(header(banner, settings.header))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
                .pipe(print(log.created))
            ;
        });

        gulp.task(`package compressed css ${org}`, function() {
            return gulp.src(`${output.uncompressed}/**/${globs.components}.${org}${globs.ignored}.css`)
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(dedupe())
            .pipe(replace(assets.uncompressed, assets.packaged))
            .pipe(concatCSS(`semantic.${org}.min.css`, settings.concatCSS))
                .pipe(gulpif(compiledConfig.hasPermission, chmod(compiledConfig.permission)))
                .pipe(minifyCSS(settings.concatMinify))
                .pipe(header(banner, settings.header))
                .pipe(gulp.dest(output.packaged))
                .pipe(print(log.created))
            ;
        });
};
```

The idea behind this being that for every organization it would update a few parameters before running the css build task.

The problem with this approach is that the build process only seems to use the acknowledge a `theme.config` file. I tried pointing the build to 'theme.org1.config', etc, but it doesn't work and doesn't provide any error.

---

**ATTEMPT 3**
???
Please let me know if I'm ignoring some obvious route. I've been working on this for a while and no matter how close I think I'm getting, nothing seems to work fully.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this to work with the following...

I updated `./semantic/build.js` to contain the following:

```
var
  gulp         = require('gulp-help')(require('gulp')),
  runSequence  = require('run-sequence'),
  print        = require('gulp-print'),
  config       = require('./config/user'),
  install      = require('./config/project/install'),
  tasks        = []
;

if(config.rtl) {
  require('./collections/rtl')(gulp);
}
require('./collections/build')(gulp);

const orgs = require('../../build/organizations.json').orgs;
module.exports = function(callback) {
    tasks.push('build-javascript');
    tasks.push('build-assets');
  for(var i = 0; i < orgs.length; i++) {
    console.info('Building Semantic');
    const org = orgs[i];

    gulp.task(`copy theme ${org}`, function() {
      return gulp.src(`./src/themes/${org}/theme.config`)
                 .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/'));
    });

    gulp.task(`build css ${org}`, [`build-css`]);

    gulp.task(`copy output ${org}`, [`build css ${org}`], function() {
      return gulp.src(`./dist/**/*.css`)
                 .pipe(gulp.dest(`../${org}/dist`));
    });

    if( !install.isSetup() ) {
      console.error('Cannot find semantic.json. Run "gulp install" to set-up Semantic');
      return 1;
    }
    tasks.push(`copy theme ${org}`);
    tasks.push(`copy output ${org}`);
  };

  runSequence(...tasks, callback);
};
```

It takes the idea that I had in **ATTEMPT 1** above and just reverses the order of operations a bit. While the build doesn't seem to acknowledge the updated `semantic.json` file, it does utilize the updated `theme.config` file, so the above script runs the build for each organization and then after that build is done it copies the built files to another directory, updates the `theme.config` file and then performs the same process again.

I have the above saved to `./build/override-semantic-ui-build.js` and then I added the following to my `package.json` file: `"postinstall": "ncp build/override-semantic-ui-build.js semantic/tasks/build.js"` so that when semantic-ui gets installed on the ci server, that build file will get overwritten with the above adaptation.

Comment: I created a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/PdUi/semantic-ui-build-multiple-themes) of this for anyone interested.

Comment: I tried to post an answer to this question, with a link to the solution I came up with (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53167787/semantic-ui-docs-with-multiple-themes-and-support-for-external-icon-libraries-li/53167788#53167788) but it got deleted by @edwin. The solution directly addresses the problem of building multiple SUI themes but his review said that it did not provide an answer to the question. I would like to ask him for a clarification but I was ton able to contact him directly.